# Is there a way to guess the trigonometric angle(radian) at which a particular fractional number is obtained?

Tags: trigonometry

While solving problems, I encounter fractional numbers like 1/250 for which I need to find the angle(radian) of Sine at which this fractional number 1/250 is obtained.

So, is there a way to make an approximation of the required angle?

Answers much appreciated!

Comment: What ratio? Without that information there is no answer.

Comment: Is the angle in degree or in radian ?

Comment: I think you should add some context. E.g. Do you want an approximation, a bound from above/below or an analytical solution or something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arc sine of small angles ($|x|<1$) can be computed using the Taylor development around $0$:

$$\arcsin(x)=x+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}\frac{x^3}3+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6}\frac{x^5}5+\cdots.$$

$$\arcsin\frac1{250}\approx0.004+0.000000008+0.000000000000064+\cdots$$

For very small arguments or low accuracy requirements, the first term can be enough.

Answer (score -1):

For small values of $x$ you can approximate

$$\sin(x)\approx x,\qquad \cos(x)\approx 1-\frac{x^2}2.$$

What *small* means for $x$ depends on the level of accuracy you need. Also this only works for angles in radian, not in degree. Now resolve for $x$ to get the angle. For example

$$ \frac1{125} = 0.008,\qquad \arcsin\left(\frac1{125}\right)\approx 0.00800008534 \,\mathrm{rad}.$$

If this is not exact enough or the value of $x$ is not that small, take a look at [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions). There are series for other functions, e.g. a direct series for $\arcsin$. The formulas above are just examples when trimming the series very early. You can always include more terms. But then its harder to resolve for $x$, so one better uses the series for $\arcsin$ directly.

Comment: Hem, rather $1-x^2/2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course. Thank you! I edited it.

Comment: Might the downvoter explain his dislike? Downvoting without explanation is like writing a bad answer himself.